# How to add custom sign in page for FBA application

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have configured FBA for my web application which is working fine with default sign in pages. So i wanted to create custonm sign in page for that application. For that i have created a custom sign in page. but when i entered credential it gives me an error as below.

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> **Stack Trace:**
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   LdapContosoAuthentication.Layouts.LdapContosoAuthentication.LoginCustmCntrlPage.Button1_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +193
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +114
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +139
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +28
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2980

Can anyone tell me how can i solved that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your custom page in layout folder and make below changes. So you can open your custom login page:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/_layouts/CustomLogin.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Have you made any change in delegate control (login control) of login.aspx page?